# Why don't my buttons work when I build the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, building

Ok so I'm new to making games but I just finished making one. But for some reason when I built the game only 3 of the buttons in the upgrade page work. All of the other buttons in the game work and they all work in the editor but when I built the game they just stopped working. And this isn't a problem with the code when you click them or hover over them they don't do anything. Can someone tell me how to fix this? If you want to check for yourself I put it on itch.io for now. It's on my creator page as ThatWeirdGameDev. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In order for your peers to help, you need to include the relevant code and/or links.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that often happens to me, is that I have something on top of a clickable button, perhaps a text box that I made very large, it will block the user's ability to click the underlying button. UI objects, if they have the property "Raycast Target" set to true (see Image component of object) do block those underneath them. If you turn off the "Raycast Target" then you can 'click through' such objects and get to your button. Often, changing screen resolutions can lead to this problem if you didn't anchor things properly (UI objects can move on top of one another and block the ones you want).